# backbone fetch: {“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”} only on mobile

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have tried to figure this out (quite a lot of posts about this issue already), but unfortunately I just can not figure it out.

I have one simple service which I'm trying to use for getting and showing some data. Everything works fine on desktop, but on mobile I just always get on every fetch following error:
alert('error: ' + JSON.stringify(XMLHttpRequest)):

> {“readyState”:0,“responseText”:“”,“status”:0,“statusText”:“error”}

Here is my code:

```
$(window).load(function(){

  var Tweet = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: function() {
      return {
        DateTime: 0,
        Tweet: ""
      };
    }
  });

  var TweetsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tweet,
    url: "http://11.112.101.221:8880/bananas"   //url was changed
  });

  this.tweetsCollection = new TweetsCollection();

  this.tweetsCollection.fetch({
      reset: true,
      success: function(request, data){
        //alert("success:" + data);
        console.log("onSuccess")
      },
      error: function(request, error){
        alert("error:" + JSON.stringify(error));
      }
  });


  var TweetsView = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName:  "li",
    template: _.template($('#item-template').html()),

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'change', this.render);
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    // Re-render the titles of the todo item.
    render: function(event) {
      event && event.preventDefault();
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
      return this;
    },

    // Remove the item, destroy the model.
    clear: function() {
      this.model.destroy();
    }
  });

  var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#warnupapp"),

    initialize: function() {
      this.listenTo(tweetsCollection, 'add', this.addOne);
      this.listenTo(tweetsCollection, 'all', this.render);
      this.main = $('#main');
      console.log("fetching..")
      tweetsCollection.fetch();
    },

    render: function() {
      this.main.show();
    },

    addOne: function(tweet) {
      var view = new TweetsView({model: tweet});
      this.$("#tweets-list").append(view.render().el);
    }

  });

  console.log("starting..")
  var App = new AppView;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

after 2 days I found out that the problem was on my server side, where I didn't allow cross-origing for my rest methods. After setting that up,..everything worked fine.